Higher homotopy groups for incompressible surfaces
If we have a closed orientable irreducible 3-manifold $M$ with infinite fundamental group and an orientable incompressible immersed surface $\Sigma$, what can we say about the higher homotopy groups of $\Sigma$? Since for $M$ all higher homotopy groups vanish, is it true that $\pi_n(\Sigma) = 0$ for $n>1$? If true, would this follow from the long exact sequence one may define for relative homotopy?

All surfaces except $S^2$ and $RP^2$ have trivial higher homotopy groups.  Since you are assuming that the surface is orientable, the only case is $S^2$, which is not incompressible by definition.
